# Why is there no transhuman tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It would apply to authors such as Zindell, Stross, and Egan just to name a few... A synonymous would be H+ or/and h+.

Comment: I don't understand what H+ and h+ mean.

Comment: Also, once you receive 150 reputation you can create tags for questions. (At time of this post, you have 141 rep) So just get 9 more rep and you can create the [tag:transhuman] tag.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: H+ or h+ are abbreviation of transhumanism.  So, all I need is two nice people to up vote this question and I shall create the tag... ^_~ ... </up_vote_whoring_enabled>

Comment: Meta.scifi.se questions don't give you reputation. You'd have to ask a question on the main site and then have upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Go ask your transhuman-related question on the main site.  I'll add the tag to it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If a tag doesn't exist, and you really think it should exist, then write the question, and flag it, and someone who has the required reputation can add it. Alternatively, bring it up in the chatroom.

Comment: No need to flag for that. Leave a comment, or even add a note at the end of the question (and whoever adds the tag will edit the body to remove the note as well).